# Ramda point-free problems with transform functions (map, etc)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have this function, which is basically mapping request parameters and query parameters to a SQL statement:

```js
function selectSingleResult(params, { order, limit, offset, fields, runset_id, txOffset, txFactor }) {
      const transformer = R.when(R.equals('values'), R.compose(knex.raw.bind(knex), applyConversion({ txOffset, txFactor })))
      const newFields = R.map(transformer , fields);

      knex('myTable').select(...newFields) // etc...
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to define `transformer`  outside the function so the function can just become:

```js
const mapFields = R.map(transformer);
function selectSingleResult(params, { order, limit, offset, fields, runset_id, txOffset, txFactor }) {
      knex('myTable').select(...mapFields(fields)) // etc...
```

The issue being that the `applyConversion` function needs arguments given to `selectSingleResult`.

This is a common issue I have with transform functions to `map`. They often require parameters other than the values being mapped over. In such cases, how can I write in point-free, or at least more testable style and not end up nesting functions so much?

Comment: Can you add some example data and expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels as though you're trying to go point-free in code where it doesn't make much sense.  But there's a contrasting notion of destructuring a large set of fields from the second parameter that doesn't seem necessary, so this seems mostly confused.  (It might actually be necessary: perhaps you're using `order`, `limit`, `offset`, and `runset_id` in the remainder of your main function.)

I think you can accomplish almost what you're asking by just introducing one more layer of calls, with something like this:

```js
const transformer = (query) => 
  R .when (R .equals ('values'), field => knex .raw (applyConversion (query) (field)))

const mapFields = R.pipe (transformer, map)

const selectSingleResult = (params, query) => {
  knex ('myTable') .select (... mapFields (query) (query .fields)) 
  // etc...
}
```

I name the second parameter to your main function `query`; it's a guess, and if that's confusing, replace all the instances of `query` with `foo` or with something meaningful to you.

Note that `mapFields` could also be written as `const mapFields = (query) => R.map (transformer (query))`, but the version above seems simpler.  Also note that I simplified `transformer` a bit.  I simply don't see any reason to try to go point-free, when you can't get all the way there.  And trying to mix point-free code with OO constructs such as `knex .raw` just seems to confuse things.

If I read the code correctly, we also might rewrite `transformer` like this:

```js
const transformer = (query) => (field) =>
  field == 'values' ? knex .raw (applyConversion (query) ('values')) : field
```

but I can't decide if that is an improvement or not.

Comment: 1/2 Thanks you have really seen into my problem there. In fact you are right - completely point free is not necessary, I was just grasping for the (wrong) words to express what I want. Now I see your solution, I can find the right words. By moving the logic  in `transformer` out of `selectSingleResult`, I can unit test it without having to involve/mock the database. I am going through the code and basically fencing in the database operations and attempting to extract anything that can be unit-tested

Comment: 2/2 I keep coming across scenarios such as this - inner functions, or compositions which need parameters from the outer, database-dependent function. In this case, it defeated me a little.... :D
P.S You were also right that the destructured parameters were used later in the function, I should have simplified my example...

Comment: "Computer Science is the discipline that believes all problems can be solved with one more layer of indirection."  In FP, that usually means, introduce another function.  It works surprisingly often!